# SSRS: Split a String into Multiple Lines in a Text-Box

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm having a problem with my SSRS report.

The data that i'm showing in some of the fields is larger than the max-width of the textbox.

How i can implements something like word-wrap in CSS, so the text can be split in multiple lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, text boxes will wrap text. Make sure you have not changed the can grow property (it is set to True by default).

If the text is too long to fit, it will increase the height of the text box to accommodate all the text.